# OpenLayers Map as texture on THREE.js plane

Tags: three.js, openlayers-3

I am looking to use an OpenLayers map as a texture for a plane in THREE.js. I know you can load a canvas element as texture for a plane material, so I've tried different ways of accomplishing that but with no success. First I create a canvas element in the DOM, with a `id=map`. Then, I create a map on it:

```
  const layers = [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
         source: new ol.source.OSM()
      })
  ];
  const map = new ol.Map({
      layers: layers,
      target: 'map',
      view: new ol.View({
         center: [-10997148, 4569099],
         zoom: 4
      })
  });
```

And then I attempt to load the map as texture in my THREE scene like:

```
const texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
texture.needsUpdate = true;
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map : texture, });
const plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

scene.add(this.plane);
```

When doing so, I can only see a black plane. The rest of elements in the scene render properly, and I can see the map perfectly fine in the 2D canvas element. If instead of using an OpenLayers map I draw on the canvas with `fillRect` or something like that, the plane gets the texture well. What am I doing wrong? (I'm using OL3 and THREE r71)

Comment: You may need to set the `texture.needsUpdate` after the map has fully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

As 2pha suggested, I needed to set `texture.needsUpdate` after the map was fully loaded, which you can ensure using the `postrender` map event from OpenLayers like:

```
map.on('postrender', () => {
    document.getElementById('map2').children[0].children[0];
    const texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
    texture.needsUpdate = true;
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture });
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(this.plane);
});
```

Comment: "map2" is the id u used for three js? Also, where is "canvas" defined ??